# Insert the pair (key & value) into the json in the position where has no answer

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working on a quiz-game and need to fill in the missing candidate's answer.

The total number of questions in the Quiz is 7.

The total number of questions that the candidate answered is 3

So need to add 4 corresponding elements in json. If the position is not available, write the value as *NOANSWER*

Json of candidate’s answer:

```
{"1": "b.) some pasta salad", "2": " a.) some bread", "5": " a.) eggs and toast" }
```

=> Insert key & value in position 3,4,6

The result i want:

```
{"1": "b.) some pasta salad","2": " a.) some bread", "3":"*NOANSWER*","4":"*NOANSWER*","5": " a.) eggs and toast","6":"*NOANSWER*", "7":"*NOANSWER*"}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach

```js
const data = {
    1: "b.) some pasta salad",
    2: " a.) some bread",
    5: " a.) eggs and toast",
};

const fillAnswers = (answers) => {
    const filled = {};
    for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        filled[i] = answers[i] || "*NOANSWER*";
    }

    return filled;
};

console.log(fillAnswers(data))
```